# Что выведет sayHi при вызове через setTimeout и почему?

Tags: javascript

Сам код:

```js
let name = "Вася";
function sayHi() {
  alert(name);
}

setTimeout(function() {
  let name = "Петя";
  sayHi();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: На вопрос что Вам уже консоль ответила, я надеюсь. А почему - из-за области видимости. внутри setTimeout переменная name находится вне области видимости вызываемой ф-ции, уберите второй let, чтобы получилось присвоение а не объявление локальной переменной и ответ изменится

Comment: то есть тут важно понимать, что область видимости переменной name в пустой функции в методе setTimeout  ограничена локально?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ сделайте как ответ, чтобы я закрыл вопрос. Спасибо!

Comment: @mobius да, только почему Вы ее назвали пустой?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну она же без аргументов, просто отрабатывает код в кавычках

Comment: вот теперь правильно назвали - "без аргументов", а пустую я бы интерпретировал как с "пустым телом"

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо!

Comment: да нет проблем, обращайтесь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На вопрос что Вам уже консоль ответила, я надеюсь.

А почему - из-за области видимости. внутри `setTimeout` переменная `name` находится вне области видимости вызываемой ф-ции.

Попробуйте уберать второй `let`, чтобы получилось присвоение а не объявление локальной переменной и ответ изменится.